# how to set AXIOS base url correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a react app and a python app. I have created a Rest API in the python program and now calling it in the react app using AXIOS. **My problem is when I'm calling the API, I can see there is an additional part which is `"HTTP://localhost:3000"` in the API Base URL and can't find where it came from**.

My API Base URL is set to `"http://127.0.0.1:5000"` So I expect to see the API call with the URL like `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/myendpoint"` but the actual result is `"HTTP://localhost:3000/http://127.0.0.1:5000/myendpoint"` **which returns 404**

this is the AXIOS call

```
axios({
       method: 'get',
       url: 'myendpoint',
       baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
      })
      .then(res => {
            console.log("data", res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
            console.log("AXIOS ERROR - ", err);
      })
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: It seems like you might be setting the global config earlier in the code.  Can you please post a reproducible example?

Comment: Try with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`